# getting value from checked checkbox in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get the values of the checked checkbox here but it is undefined because it becomes an array.. Please help me how to do it.. thank you..

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="a" name="letter[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="b" name="letter[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="c" name="letter[]" />
<input type="button" value="submit"  onclick="rani()" />
</form>
<script>
function rani(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:{
            radha:$("[name=letter]").val(),
            },
        success:function(msg){
            alert(msg);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you will get selected checkbox values in a variable `checkbox_value` and later split by `|`.

```
$("#btn_").on('click', function () {
    var checkbox_value = "";
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (ischecked) {
            checkbox_value += $(this).val() + "|";
        }
    });
    alert(checkbox_value);
    // your awesome code calling ajax
});
```

**[Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qP3tE/1/)**

Comment: cool.. thanks a lot @Satinder singh.. this is exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function rani() {
    var letters = $('input[name="letter[]"]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get()
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
            radha: letters,
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    })
}
```

otherwise try

```
function rani() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: it only submit the last one the is checked

Comment: I tried data: $('form').serialize() but it only save the first checked value from the checkbox with same name tag.