# how to fetch data when an item entered a select box?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm referring to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a1gsgh11/16/.

How can I also fetch data from database for each category as soon as it that enters the left box and display the list below each category like following?

Say I select primary , university from the checkbox.Under this two category there are items stored in db. How to show them below each category without triggering any event using ajax?

exm: 

primary
List 1
List 2
List 3

University
List 1
List 2

something I tried,
script:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','wordblend_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"wordblend_db");
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects WHERE level_id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>

<th>Subject Name</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

HTML:

trigger click event on each category:

```
<select multiple size="10" id="from" name="users" onClick="showUser(this.value)">
</select>
```

And display like this,but not under each category:

```
<div class="inner_box_wrapper">
     <select multiple id="to" size="10" name="topics[]"></select>
</div>
```

complete html

```
 <main>
      <div id="main" class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
              <h1>Text</h1>
              <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sem orci,
                  suscipit eu lorem a, volutpat varius orci. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla ac magna id sapien molestie sodales.
                  Integer eget diam diam. Vivamus vestibulum, justo non ullamcorper sodales, justo orci commodo magna, eu 
                  elementum elit enim elementum tortor. Suspendisse id nulla in felis feugiat porta. Vestibulum et nulla interdum,
                  elementum diam a, gravida ipsum. Cras elementum tincidunt libero, quis bibendum dui placerat ac. Cum sociis natoque
                  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis eget tristique justo, a rutrum purus. 
                  Nullam fermentum lorem lectus, nec ullamcorper ipsum eleifend in. Ut tempus volutpat
                  commodo. Maecenas pellentesque et nibh eget laoreet

              </p>
                <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
              <h1>
                  A. In 20 seconds, set an hourly rate and subjects that you can tutor.

              </h1>
          </div>
               </div>             
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-2 columns">
                      <span class="title">Your Hourly Rate</span>
                  </div>
                   <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-6 columns">
                      <span class="title">Your Subjects</span>
                      <br/>



                      <div class="row check">
                          <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">

                              <input type="checkbox" name="level" id="level" value="1"><label>Primary</label><br/>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="level" id="level" value="2"><label>Upper Secondary</label><br/>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="level" id="level" value="3"><label>University</label><br/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
                               <input type="checkbox" name="level" id="level" value="4"><label>Lower Secondary</label><br/>
                               <input type="checkbox" name="level" id="level" value="5"><label>Pre University</label><br/>
                               <input type="checkbox" name="level" id="level" value="6"><label>Skills/Languages</label><br/>
                          </div>
                      </div>


                  </div>
                   <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns">
                       <span class="title">Your Posts</span>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
           <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-2 columns">
               <div class="rate">
                   <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-9 columns">
                       <input type="text" name="rate" value="" placeholder="RM">
                   </div>
                   <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-2 columns plus">
                       +
                   </div>

               </div>   

           </div>
           <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-10 columns">
               <div class="">
                <!--<output>0 are checked<p>No Values</p></output>-->

               <form name="selection" method="post" onSubmit="return selectAll()">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns box_wrapper">
                           <div class="inner_box_wrapper">
                         <select multiple size="10" id="from" name="users" onClick="showUser(this.value)">

                         </select>

                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns box_wrapper text-center">
                           <div class="inner_box_wrapper">
                           <div class="controls"> 
                          <!-- <a class="moveAll1">&gt;&gt;</a> -->
                               <a class="moveSelected1">Add &#8594;</a> 
                               <a class="moveSelected2">Remove &#8592;</a> 
                           <!-- <a class="moveAll2" href="#">&lt;&lt;</a>-->
                           </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns box_wrapper">
                           <div class="inner_box_wrapper">
                           <select multiple id="to" size="10" name="topics[]"></select>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>




               </form>
                   <!--hide-->
                  <div id="txtHint"><b>Level info will be listed here...</b></div>
               </div> 
           </div>


      </div>

      <!--availability -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
              <h1>
                  B. In 20 seconds, tell your students about your availability for tutoring
              </h1>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 large-centered columns">
              <table class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 large-centered columns">
                  <tr>
                      <th></th><th>Weekdays</th><th>Weekends</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="text-right">Morning<br/>(8am-12m)</td>
                      <td>
                          <div class="onoffswitch">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                           <div class="onoffswitch">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" checked>
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="text-right">Afternoon<br/>(12am-6m)</td>
                       <td>
                            <div class="onoffswitch">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch3" checked>
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                       </td>
                      <td>
                           <div class="onoffswitch">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch4" checked>
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="text-right">Evening<br/>(6am-10m)</td>
                       <td>
                            <div class="onoffswitch">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch5" checked>
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                       </td>
                      <td>
                           <div class="onoffswitch">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch6" checked>
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!--create account -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
              <h1>
                  C. In 1 minute, fill-out your details to create an account.
              </h1>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-8 large-centered columns">
              <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
                  <li><div class="inner_li text-center">Name</div></li>
                  <li><div class="inner_li text-center">Email</div></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
                  <li><div class="inner_li text-center">Postcode</div></li>
                  <li><div class="inner_li text-center">Phone Number</div></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
                  <li><div class="inner_li text-center">Password</div></li>
                  <li>

                      <div class="onoffswitch2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch2-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch7" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch2-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch2-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch2-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!--submit -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">
              <h1>
                  By clicking submit, you agree to our terms and conditions. 
              </h1>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
      </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: What is the status now?

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS data can be fetched upon click n it list out outside the boxes.

Comment: Now what you are getting from the server with this code?

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS, Im getting the list for each category.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
```

txtHint is the id of target block, so you have to define this id where you want your result: If you want in div then it will be like

```
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

then whatever you have echo on getuser.php will come inside this div

Comment: <div id="txtHint"></div>  is working but I want result to display right after it enters the box and not after clicking

Comment: what is the use of this

<select multiple size="10" id="from" name="users" onClick="showUser(this.value)">
 

                         </select>

You can call this in checkbox

onClick="showUser(this.value)

Comment: refer it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131800/getting-value-from-checked-checkbox-in-ajax

Answer (score 0):

After few days of trying this and that, finally I came up with a solution for my problem. To show checkbox value by category, I learnt group in multiple select box should some into the scene.

So my first script now, would give a call to a function to fetch data from database if checkbox is checked, passing the checked value to be used as  in group in select box.

```
<script>
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {  
     var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
        sendtobox(selectedval);
     }
      else {
        $("optgroup."+selectedval).remove();
     }
    });
</script>
```

This below function would simply fetch data and append to the box below where I want to show them all.

```
function sendtobox(param)
            {
                 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText !== null) {
            var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('show');
            ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText + ajaxElm.innerHTML; // append in front
             }
                //document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            }

                 xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+param,true);
                 xmlhttp.send();

            }
```

And my getuser.php now not using table but  as below:

```
<?php
 $q= intval($_GET['q']);
 $r=$_GET['r'];
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"test_db");
//$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects WHERE level_id = '".$q."'";
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_levels,tbl_subjects WHERE tbl_levels.level_id=tbl_subjects.level_id AND tbl_levels.level_id='$q'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $levels=$row['level_name'];
    $levels_id=$row['level_id'];
    $subjects= $row['subject_name'];
    $subjects_id= $row['subject_id'];


    ?>
   <optgroup label="<?php echo $levels;?>" class="<?php echo $q;?>">
       <option value="<?php echo $subjects_id;?>"><?php echo $subjects;?></option>
</optgroup>

    <?php

}

?>
```