# Sending checked checkbox values

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm doing a filter-by specifications on an app, and was wondering how can I implement without reloading the whole page (which I'm trying to convert to AJAX rather than PHP/Laravel alone). However my filters are based off on foreach loops

```
@foreach($cores as $core)
<li style="list-style: none;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="core[]" id="cores" class="form-check-control" value="{{ $core->value }}"> {{ $core->value }}
</li>
@endforeach
```

Am trying $('#cores').val() but it is not working. I'm thinking of call it by class name then looping it to check if it is checked but it may affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is creating multiple elements with the same id, so accessing it this way won't work. Remove the id element from the checkbox, and refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19132105/6504812) answer for getting the value of the checked boxes in JS

Comment: how can i do further call to it? I've tried using class name but didn't work ````$(".checklistA:checkbox").each(function () {}); ````

Comment: Try $("input.checklistA:checkbox").each(function() {});

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way and u can take the values

```
@foreach($cores as $core)
<li style="list-style: none;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="core[{{ $core->value }} || paste something unique for the checkbox]" id="cores" class="form-check-control" value="1"> {{ $core->value }}
</li>
@endforeach
```

after that u can foreach $core and take only values that are seted and filter by them

Comment: how do i call this on jquery/ajax?